# Gulp livereload from build folder

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Everything is working fine, except that LiveReload is not watching for changes, and therefore it does not auto-reload the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Gulp file:

```js
// Gulp.js configuration
var
 // modules
 gulp = require('gulp'),
 newer = require('gulp-newer'),
 imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
 pug = require('gulp-pug'),
 htmlclean = require('gulp-htmlclean'),
 concat = require('gulp-concat'),
 deporder = require('gulp-deporder'),
 stripdebug = require('gulp-strip-debug'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
 assets = require('postcss-assets'),
 autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
 mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker'),
 cssnano = require('cssnano'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),

 // development mode?
 devBuild = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),

 // folders
 folder = {
  src: 'src/',
  build: 'build/'
 };


// image processing
gulp.task('images', function () {
 var out = folder.build + 'images/';
 return gulp.src(folder.src + 'images/**/*')
  .pipe(newer(out))
  .pipe(imagemin({
   optimizationLevel: 5
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(out));
});

// Pug processing
gulp.task('pug', function buildHTML() {
 var out = folder.build
 return gulp.src(folder.src + 'views/*.pug')
  .pipe(pug({
   pretty: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(out))
});

// HTML processing
gulp.task('html', ['images'], function () {
 var
  out = folder.build + 'html/',
  page = gulp.src(folder.src + 'html/**/*')
  .pipe(newer(out));

 // minify production code
 if (!devBuild) {
  page = page.pipe(htmlclean());
 }

 return page.pipe(gulp.dest(out));
});

// JavaScript processing
gulp.task('js', function () {

 var jsbuild = gulp.src(folder.src + 'js/**/*')
  .pipe(deporder())
  .pipe(concat('main.js'));

 if (!devBuild) {
  jsbuild = jsbuild
   .pipe(stripdebug())
   .pipe(uglify());
 }

 return jsbuild.pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'js/'));

});

// CSS processing
gulp.task('css', ['images'], function () {

 var postCssOpts = [
  assets({
   loadPaths: ['images/']
  }),
  autoprefixer({
   browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 2%']
  }),
  mqpacker
 ];

 if (!devBuild) {
  postCssOpts.push(cssnano);
 }

 return gulp.src(folder.src + 'scss/styles.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
   outputStyle: 'nested',
   imagePath: 'images/',
   precision: 3,
   errLogToConsole: true
  }))
  .pipe(postcss(postCssOpts))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'css/'));

});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
 browserSync.init({
  server: {
   baseDir: folder.build
  },
  port: 3000
 });
});

// run all tasks
gulp.task('run', ['pug', 'html', 'css', 'js']);

// watch for changes
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function () {

 // image changes
 gulp.watch(folder.src + 'images/**/*', ['images']);

 // pug changes
 gulp.watch(folder.src + 'views/**/*', ['pug'], browserSync.reload);

 // html changes
 gulp.watch(folder.src + 'html/**/*', ['html'], browserSync.reload);

 // javascript changes
 gulp.watch(folder.src + 'js/**/*', ['js'], browserSync.reload);

 // css changes
 gulp.watch(folder.src + 'scss/**/*', ['css'], browserSync.reload);

});


// default task
gulp.task('default', ['run', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample of our working `watch` gulp configuration is like:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

watch('./src/**/*.html', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});
```